# Can ActiveStorage::PurgeJob be enqueued to other than `default`?

Tags: rails-activestorage

There wasn't any queue named `default` in our Rails code. But it seems Sidekiq sets queue for ActiveStorage::PurgeJob as `default`. That was why `purge_later` never worked.

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: .. ) to Sidekiq(default) with arguments
```

Is there a way to have different queue name than "default" here? I couldn't find documentation about it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Setting the name of the Active Job queue used by Active Storage

You can change the queue used by Active Storage for its async jobs at the configuration level like this

```
config.active_storage.queue = :low_priority
```

To make this an application-wide change, put it into your `application.rb`. For environment-specific changes, put it into the relevant environment file under `config/environments`

See the documentation here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-storage

Comment: Thank you. By the way for a note, it was ActiveJob that sets queue name "default" as default https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_name.rb#L10

Answer (score 4):

This did not work for me, instead the following worked

```
config.active_storage.queues = Hash.new(:default)
```

This is due to purge_job.rb looking up the queue name like so

```
queue_as { ActiveStorage.queues[:purge] }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 7.1, setting `config.active_storage.queue` doesn't impact the queue used by the `PurgeJob`.

This did the trick:

```rb
config.active_storage.queues.analysis = "my-queue"
config.active_storage.queues.purge = "my-queue"
```